# Can a private pilot legally act as a safety pilot for an instrument student performing approaches under the hood?

Tags: faa-regulations, ppl, instrument-rating, safety-pilot

Someone is looking for a safety pilot so that they can build instrument hours under the hood and practice instrument holds / approaches. Is there any reg that would prevent me (a private pilot) from acting as a safety pilot during this flight?

Would I need to hold an instrument rating for us to legally perform instrument procedure practice? We are both only private pilots, but the other pilot is receiving instrument training.

Answer (score 2):

The safety pilot must possess a private pilot certificate with category and class ratings appropriate to the aircraft being flown [91.109(c)(1)(i)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.109)

> (c) No person may operate a civil aircraft in simulated instrument flight unless -
>
> 1. The other control seat is occupied by a safety pilot who possesses at least:
>
>    i. A private pilot certificate with category and class ratings appropriate to the aircraft being flown; or
>
>    ii. For purposes of providing training for a solo cross-country endorsement under § 61.93 of this chapter, a flight instructor certificate with an appropriate sport pilot rating and meets the requirements of § 61.412 of this chapter.

That's the only requirement.